# Cannot read property 'set' of undefined when List<String> return in ui:inputSelect

Tags: lightning-aura-components, controller, picklist, dynamic, ui-inputselect

All I want to do is retrieve picklist options from a custom object and fetch the inputSelect element in a lighning controller. I am trying this way.. but I am getting an error.. If someone knows any other way to achieve this goal I will appreciate a lot..

I get the following error when trying to return a List of strings to fetch a inputSelect with retrieved salesforce custom object data: ***Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'set' of undefined]***

This is my code:

COMPONENT:

```
  <ui:inputSelect  aura:id="InputDDSelectDynamic" class="slds-select"  change="{!c.onPicklistChange}"/>
```

CONTROLLER JS in doInit function:

```
   helper.getOptionsPicklist(component,"DD");
```

HELPER JS:

```
    getOptionsPicklist: function(component, valor) {
    var action = component.get("c.getOptionsPicklist");
    action.setParams({
                "valor": valor
            });

    var inputsel = component.find("InputDDSelectDynamic");
     alert(inputsel);
    var opts=[];
    action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
        for(var i=0;i< a.getReturnValue().length;i++){

            opts.push({"class": "optionClass", label: a.getReturnValue()[i], value: a.getReturnValue()[i]});
        }

        inputsel.set("v.options", opts);


    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);

}
```

APEX CONTROLLER:

```
      @AuraEnabled
public static List<String> getOptionsPicklist(String valor){
    List<String> options = new List<String>();
    String valorSF;
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult;

    if(valor.equals('DD')){ //  
        fieldResult = QuoteLineItem.SpaceDD__c.getDescribe();
    }

    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
    for (Schema.PicklistEntry f: ple) {
        options.add(f.getLabel());
    }

    return options;
}
```

**** The inputsel returns "undefined".... I dont know why, its like I cant get the inputSelect element...

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.... I was calling to the apex controller in the doInit function but this inputselect was not visible when the component was open, so I call apex controller once this part is visible with aura:if

Sorry and thank you!!